# XSLT or Perl changes the href encoding

Tags: html, xml, windows, perl, xslt

I am using a `xml`, `xslt`, and a perl file as is in the following link.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/yutt5ueitec4cav/Test.zip

(It is a sample from a very large file)

I would like to run perl file and generate an HTML file as an output.

It generates an HTML file but for the linking between right-hand-side table and the link-hand-side there is an error. By clicking on the right links it jumps to the left hand-side links. It works for all links except for one(in real case for more cases) case. This case includes a German letters. It is not translated to the HTML correctly.

Would you please let me know is the problem from Perl or XSLT?
Thanks a lot for your helps in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what's being output?

Comment: Thanks, I have added this line with "UTF-8". Please take a look at the edit version

Comment: Please show the rest of your XSLT

Comment: We need to see a [***Minimal,. Complete, and Verifiable example***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can run your transform ourselves. It's not fair to ask for free help and leave us to guess about the most of the problem. If you don't want to show your complete data then you should reduce the problem to something smaller that displays the same issue.

Comment: Need a little more information than 'other letters'.. what other letters? Can you copy & paste exactly what you're getting out instead of this "ä"?

Comment: I have voted to close this question on the grounds that it is off-topic. *"Questions seeking debugging help* (**"why isn't this code working?"**) *must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* **in the question itself** *."*

Comment: `Test%282%29.zip` is a strange name for a file, and having downloaded it (a 64KB file, is that right?) it is not a valid zip archive.

Comment: I have uploaded once again

Answer (score 3):

A URL must have a *scheme*, such as `http`, and may contain only 8-bit characters. So the resulting `<a>` tag should look like this

```
<a href="file:///C:/test/K%C3%A4se/failedImages/failed_1.png">
```

You are not adding the correct scheme, but apart from that, if the **ä** is being expressed as `%C3%A4` (which is the UTF-8-encoding of the character) then it is correct

In addition, you shouldn't code a `<meta>` element into your XSLT code as it is just text to the XSLT engine. Something like

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

should be added using

```
<xsl:output media-type="text/html" encoding="UTF-8" />
```

so that the XSLT engine is aware of the settings and can generate a `<meta>` element together with data that matches it

You will also want `method="html"` and `indent="yes"`

Comment: The OP has confused everyone by giving incomplete information, but I'm pretty sure this is the correct diagnosis. If you're using the HTML output method, then the XSLT serializer will perform URL-encoding on URI-valued attributes such as `img/@src`, and this will percent-encode `ä` as `%C3%A4`, which is the correct representation of a URL in HTML. The fact that the value of the attribute is actually a Windows filename rather than a URI is not something that the XSLT processor will worry about.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your all comments and your answer.
Well, it is not secret, but I was away from office and then have not seen the comments and answers. I am trying to edit my question in the way that  it shows the problem in a small code/example.
But for now I could say that you are right the character which is shown in html is: `C:\test\tst_K%C3%A4se%5CfailedImages%5Cfailed_1.png`. But when I am clicking on the page it shows nothing. Because html file shows like this in explorer: `C:\test\tst_KÃ¤se\failedImages\failed_1.png`.

Comment: @Royeh: That would be, as I said, because you have no *scheme* on your URL. You need to prefix the path with `file:///` for paths on your local system. The path separators should also be converted to *forward* slashes, but you may have some success with backslashes if you use a prefix of `file://` instead of `file:///`. You will have to experiment.

Comment: @Borodin: it is already with `file:///`. One can see with keeping mouse on the image. But my problem is by clicking on the link gives wrong letter for "ä". When I change "Ã¤" to the "ä", it works fine.

Comment: also my paths are relative rather than fixed paths.

Comment: @Royeh: A path starting with `C:\\` isn't relative.

Comment: @Royeh: The two bytes hex C3 A4  correspond to the UTF-8 encoding of the character `ä` and also to the Windows-1252 encoding of the  two characters `Ã¤`. Essentially, the XSLT processor is doing what you asked and encoding the character in UTF-8, while Windows is expecting something else. Recent versions of Windows use UTF-8 encoding; what version of Windows are you using? When you say *"When I change "Ã¤" to the "ä", it works fine"* what are you doing? Editing the XML file? What encoding is your editor set to use?

Comment: I have created an example finally. Would you please take a look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding issue, the best suggestion I could make without further information is to make sure your input XML and XSLT both have headers that specify the encoding you're using, and make sure you have an `<xsl:output encoding=".."/>` in the root of your XSLT that matches it. The XML header should look like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding=".."?>`

I'm fairly sure your problem is most likely that your input XML either doesn't have one and it's assuming the wrong encoding, or it's got the wrong encoding specified. You need to make sure the XML declaration on your input is correct to start with, otherwise that `ä` isn't going to be read correctly.

EDIT: Based on your comments on Borodin's answer, it sounds more like whatever's consuming your output is reading it as the wrong encoding; he's right, what you're getting from your XSLT is valid URI-encoded UTF8, whatever you have that's generating that link/opening explorer is URI decoding it as if it were Windows-1252.